# ADF Tumbling window trigger: disable backfill/catchup for non prod environments

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, orchestration

Having experience working with Airflow I don't seem to find something similar to [the catchup functionality](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#catchup) in ADF to disable backfill for Tumbling Window Trigger in case it's not needed - for example running ADF on dev environment.

Using ADF Schedule trigger is not an option since they:

- don't honor dependencies on other pipelines
- don't do the catchup if it's needed e.g. for prod environment

Is there any other way to disable a catchup for Tumbling Window Trigger ?